# Using SUMIFS to ignore a negative number

Tags: excel, sumifs

I've seen a few solutions to this problem using SUMIF to ignore a negative number, however, I need to use SUMIFS for this particular issue.

My SUMIFS function is somewhat simple

`=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,B1)`

Where I just want to sum all of the values in column A based on a descriptor in column B. However for some of my column A values are negative and I need this to be excluded from the summation.

Answer (score 0):

Add that criteria:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,B1,A:A,">0")
```

Comment: I'd used the ">0" but didn't know I needed to put another A:A before it. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like

```
 =SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,B1, A:A ">" & 0)
```

work for you?